# AutoLayout UITableView within UITableViewCell Dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to put a uitableview within a uitableviewcell.The number of cells are dynamic, and the inner table view height should be the contentsize height. (Please refer to the images below) The first time the view loads it does not calculate the height of the cell correctly in that it only expands to the height of the label. After scrolling down and then back up so the cell reloads, it calculates the height correctly. Anyone have any ideas to fix this. I have included the cell's, the label's, and the inner tableview's constrains.

```
- (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority {

    CGRect rect = self.answerOptionsTable.frame;
    rect.size.height = MAXFLOAT;

    self.answerOptionsTable.frame = rect;
    [self.answerOptionsTable layoutIfNeeded];


    CGSize returnedSize;
    if ( self.answerOptionsTable.contentSize.height > self.lblQuestion.frame.size.height )
    {
        returnedSize = self.answerOptionsTable.contentSize;
    }
    else
    {
        returnedSize = self.lblQuestion.frame.size;
    }

    // add some padding
    returnedSize.height += 20;

    return returnedSize;
 }
```

Cell Constraints

[image: Cell Constraints]

Table Constraints

[image: Table Constrains]

Label Constraints

[image: Label Constraints]

Initial draw

[image: Before Cell redraw]

After reload of cell

[image: After cell redraw]

Here is another example with smaller number of rows initial draw
[image: Smaller cell]

Smaller number of rows after cell redraw
[image: Smaller cell after cell redraw]